# Where is android sdk version defined?

Tags: android

Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) defines

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
      android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
      android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

In **AndroidManifest.xml**, but a new project created by Android Studio does not contain it. Where are the sdk versions defined?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare it like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="25" 
          android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```

it will be ignored when you build it with **Gradle**, but other build systems might certainly rely on it being there.

In your **app build.gradle**, you can define it as the following:

```
android {

  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25

    applicationId 'com.example.app'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }

  ...
}
```

And ***please be noted*** that you need to match the API Level in those:

- compileSdkVersion
- buildToolsVersion
- targetSdkVersion

And if you add [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) to your dependencies, you also need to match it to your API Level. For example, if you use **API Level 25** as the targetSdkVersion, you need to add the following when using **appCompat-V7**:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all your gradle and sdk detetails you will get in build.gradle (mosule:app) file of gradle script
you can even change them here but you need to rebuild your project again after changing anything in here[the following link will show you image of this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTE7v.jpg)